# How to import YAML file into API gateway using cdk in TypeScript?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I am a beginner with cdk.
I have created an API Gateway and added resources and methods to it.
Now I want import a swagger/YAML file into the API Gateway using CDK.

I have found this feature to be very clear over the console but I'm unable to find or understand how it is possible to do so using CDK.
I have tried searching the documents but I only found importing cloud formation templates using cdk, Also there were no answers for a similar question which was asked in 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JSON import example from the CDK [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway-readme.html#openapi-definition).  The CloudFormation [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-body) suggest YAML is also accepted (the CDK uploads the spec file to S3, from where CloudFormation takes over).

```js
const api = new apigateway.SpecRestApi(this, 'books-api', {
  apiDefinition: apigateway.ApiDefinition.fromAsset('path-to-file.json')
});
```